# gulp error with formatting

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am learning to use gulp and have followed through a tutorial.  I am trying to concat js files my code is:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task["concatScripts", function() {
 return   gulp.src(['js/jquery.js',
              'js/foundation.equalizer.js', 'js/foundation.reveal.js'])
    .pipe(concat("app.js"))
    .pip(gulp.dest("js"));
}];
```

my error code is:

```
    $ gulp concatScripts
[21:33:21] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\Treehouse notes\website-optimization\work\gulpfile.js
[21:33:21] Task 'concatScripts' is not in your gulpfile
[21:33:21] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?  Also it did not state to, however I linked the gulp.js file to write the code for gulp in to my html, is this correct?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have syntax error task is a function i.e. `gulp.task("concatScripts", function(){})`

Comment: Thank you for your time.  It is now working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation at [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) and the code example: Instead of calling `gulp.task['` you should make a function call:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('concatScripts', function() {
  return gulp.src('./js/*.js') // <-- Or an array of files
    .pipe(concat('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./js/'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the link will be helpful for me to get my head around it more.